# Как правильно поставить паузу в цикле?

Tags: java, циклы

Метод `blind()`, который должен каждую секунду стирать по одной строчке текста, вместо этого он стирает весь текст целиком. Как правильно поставить цикл на паузу?

```
public void blind() {
    result = textIn.getText();
    String[] textBlind = result.split("\n");
    String[] textSpace = {""};

    for (int i = 0; i < textBlind.length; i++) {
        result = result.replaceAll(textBlind[i], textSpace[0]);
        textIn.setText(result);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Какую UI-библиотеку используете? Swing?

Comment: использую JavaFX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX, как и многие другие GUI-библиотеки, однопоточна. При создании окна создаётся *Поток Обработки Событий*<sup>1</sup>, внутри которого будет работать цикл событий и обработчики событий. Вы не должны пытаться из главного потока или любого другого потока взаимодействовать с элементами графического интерфейса - это приведёт к сбою. Вы не должны внутри обработчиков событий запускать потоки - это приведёт к сбою. И вы не должны останавливать поток - это приведёт к сбою.

Конкретно в вашем случае проблему можно решить использованием [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html):

```
public class Eraser extends Application  {
    private TextArea textArea;
    private Timeline timeline;

    public void blind() {
        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), ae -> {
            String text = textArea.getText();
            int position = text.lastIndexOf('\n');
            if (position > 0) {
                textArea.setText(text.substring(0, position));
            }
            else {
                textArea.setText("");
                timeline.stop();
            }
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Timeline Demo");

        textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setText("Aaa\nBbb\nCcc\nDdd\nEee\nFff");

        VBox vbox = new VBox(textArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        blind();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

1. На самом деле поток обработки событий в JavaFX называется [JavaFX Application Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/architecture/jfxpub-architecture.htm#sthref4).